# With AMD CrossFire enabled, I experience some flickering in Simcity (2013)

Tags: simcity-2013, graphics-card

I have AMD Radeon HD 5970 graphics cards, which are using CrossFire technology.

I have experienced some flickering in the game when CrossFire is enabled. I have read something about AFR friendly mode helping a bit.

**How do I get rid of this flickering? Is there an AMD Catalyst application profile setting I can change?**

Comment: To the downvoters: We encourage users to leave a comment when downvoting so that the OP knows how to improve their question. When down votes are left without comments and the reasons for doing so are unclear, you'll often see users (like myself) wanting to know the reason why.

Comment: Might take a look at [this](http://www.rage3d.com/board/showthread.php?t=33878865). I don't understand enough of it to turn it into an answer.

Comment: Where did you read about AFR friendly mode?  Have you tried it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific type of computer. It should be made broader.

Comment: Edited the question to make it less 'primarily opinion-based' (as per close vote reason). Hopefully, that should allow this question to be eventually reopened.

Comment: @kotekzot Any particular reason for [this edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/108671/4) (rephrasing the title to put "in Simcity (2013)" at the end instead of the start)? I'm thinking that it's a minor, unnecessary edit, but maybe you have a good reason for doing it.

Comment: @galacticninja the title as it was seemed like a forced tag drop.

Comment: @kotekzot What do you mean by "tag drop"? Do you mean it's redundant to put the game name in the title as it's already in the tag? If yes, your edit should be to remove the game name in the title. As it is, I believe it's too minor of an edit.

Comment: @galacticninja no, I mean the tag is forced into the sentence where it doesn't belong. "Game x: how do I Y" is bad, "How do i Y in game X" is acceptable. I could've renamed it to "Screen flicker with Crossfire enabled", but there isn't much difference between the 2 options except for the number of edited characters.

Answer (score 1):

The best for now is probably disabling crossfire, i get same issues even blue screen with 7950 crossfire. Simcity doesnt like dual graphics cards i believe.

Answer (score -1):

Run Frameless window mode or disable